# selenium webdriver stop loading when switching pages

Tags: python, selenium

python3.7  chrome

when I open the first page and it finishes loading

then I open the second page with the following code

```
open_google_vision_js = 'window.open("https://cloud.google.com/vision/")'
browser.execute_script(open_google_vision_js)
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
```

When the code finish switch to window

At this time, when I perform any operation(for example `print(browser.current_url)`), it will cause second page stop loading.

Actually the second page is not fully loaded.

If no operations are performed(`WebDriverWait` or `print(browser.title`), the second page loads normally.

I want to know what caused the second page to stop loading?

Comment: I understand https://cloud.google.com/vision/ is not the site you are trying to load... because it loads before `print(browser.current_url)` is printed... so my question to you is what site are you trying to load? if you can't shear that, maybe tell us if it's an angular site...

Comment: @Moshe Slavin the website I want to load is [cloud.google.com/vision](http://cloud.google.com/vision). I have already said that in my question. the second page opens this URL.
`print(browser.current_url)` is just an example. I might need `WebDriverWait` to wait for [cloud.google.com/vision](http://cloud.google.com/vision) to finish loading and then proceed to the next step.

Comment: ok, I so your question is why the page doesn't finish to load if you add any type of action after the switch?

Comment: can you add a more specific action to do we can try to help you... as far as loading when you switch to window it does not wait to load... just like the `get()`

Comment: @Moshe Slavin I also tried to use `get()` after switching pages, but any operation will cause this new page to stop loading.

Comment: here is a link to the demo program [gist demo](https://gist.github.com/xueyefengbao/dac01384dad40369582a72535459bfab)

Comment: see my research in the answer let me know if this helps you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to check out this chromedriver issue: [Chromedriver hangs on any type of call when page is being redirected in popup](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2660)

It has the same problem with second page not loading. In this issue you will find link to chromium bug.

Also you'll find a workaround for this problem. Try to enable `--disable-site-isolation-trials` parameter and check whether it helps you or not.

Comment: Thank you for your help, after I added `--disable-site-isolation-trials`, everything worked fine.